# How to create Listbox dynamically wpf

Tags: wpf, dynamic, listbox, datacontext

I want to create listbox dynamically [codebehind c#]. Its datasource is class object.

```
class sample
{
  string filepath;
  string id;
  string trackName;
}
```

Needs:

1. Display trackName as listbox item in the listbox [dynamically].

Code:

```
sample samp=GetBL.GetValue();
ListBox lbTrack = new ListBox();
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
lbTrack.ItemSource = samp;
```

Geetha.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that exposes an `ObservableCollection<sample>` as a property named, say, `Samples`.  Create an instance of this class, populate its collection, and add the class to the window's resource dictionary, with a key of, let's say, `Data`.  Override `ToString()` in the `sample` class to make it return what you want to appear in the `ListBox`.

Then do this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Data, Path=Samples}"/>
```

Without overriding `ToString()`, you can specify a display binding:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{StaticResource Data, Path=Samples}" 
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=trackName"/>
```

Note that `trackName` must be a property, not a field.

You'll notice that I'm not programmatically creating WPF controls, and am instead using data binding to do it for me.  This is an essential, fundamental concept of WPF application development.